# Using VBA macro to take scraped data and create tables based on certain values

Tags: excel, vba

I admit I am completely new to Excel VBA. At the moment, I am in charge of generating a summary of data based of an automatically generated table of data spit out on a site. I already figured out how to scrape the data onto my Excel thankfully.

The scraped data is something of the following format:

**TYPE | Number_Days_Logged | (a bunch of other important columns of data in row (6-7 items)|**

What I need to do now is the following.

I need to do an if statement or comparison. There are two "types" under the type column. Let's say 0 and 1. I really only need type '1', so I need to filter out any 'type' 0's. Then I need to check the "number_days_logged". If this number is <= 1, I need to add it to a table with other entries with this condition. I then need to check "number_days_logged" for entries >= 85 and <100. These results will need to be put into a second table. Finally, I need to do the same this for values >= 100.

So in the end I need three different tables, the first with a green color formatting, then orange, and finally red. Each table need to be titled with the above information, though I really only need data from specific columns in each row. (each row is labeled, I just need a specific few columns)

This seems incredibly complicated to me, but I am willing to learn. If anyone can prod me in the correct direction, or make it simpler I would appreciate it. I can add any other details as required.

Comment: Please remember to upvote/accept any answers you find helpful. Show recognition for those who spent time to answer your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think select statements are pretty clear and they tend to run a little faster too.

```
dim typeRange as range
set typeRange = range(cells(startRow,col),cells(stopRow,col))
dim entry as range
dim currentRow as integer
for each entry in typeRange
    currentRow = entry.Row
    if entry.value=1 then
        select case cells(currentRow,'Number_Days_Logged's column').value
            case is<=1
                'copy and paste or transcribe the cells however you need them done.
            case is<85
                'do nothing
            case is<100
                'copy and paste or transcribe the cells however you need them done.
            case is>=100
                'copy and paste or transcribe the cells however you need them done.
        end select
    end if
next
```

Comment: Thank you both. What I did in the interim was use the "record macro" feature. What I want works, but isn't very eloquent, nor is it re-usable. Any suggested resources for a recent college grad to tackle excel for a work environment? Thank you both again.

Comment: Just know to ask questions, take your time, think of alternatives, explore menus and get real good at Googleing. The last one is a real skill.

Answer (score 0):

You would first setup the tables with the colors you wanted, and (for this code) a named range for the data.  I'd probably used named ranges for your tables also.  Here's the skeleton of the VBA code.

```
Dim testrow As Range

For Each testrow in ActiveSheet.Range("Scraped Data")
  If testrow.Cells(1) = 1 Then
    If testrow.Cells(2) <= 1 Then
      <add to 0-days table>
    ElseIf testrow.Cells(2) >= 85 AND testrow.Cells(2) < 100 Then
      <put in 2nd table>
    ElseIf testrow.Cells(2) >= 100 Then
      <put in third table>
    End If
  End If
Next testrow
```